# IE 11 doesn't preserve session between pages in my Java Web Application

Tags: apache, internet-explorer, java, tomcat, session

I have a Java web application running in Apache/Tomcat. The web application runs fine in the latest Chrome & Firefox builds, and in older versions of Internet Explorer (IE) such as IE 8. The application fails though in IE 11. The error that occurs is as follows: I login to the application fine but when attempt to navigate to a new page a new session is generated which means the application doesn't recognize I'm logged in.  By printing the session id I can see how the id is different:

```
String sessID = request.getSession().getId();
System.out.println(sessID);
```

I have read a number of articles some of which have solutions. I have seen two solutions listed; one for Asp.NET applications (doesn't help me) and the other related to changing the default session settings in IE:

```
Internet options > Privacy> Advanced> Override automatic cookie handling.
```